# Calling system's file upload window with anchor tag using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Please is it possible to call up the system's file upload window with an anchor tag?
And if it is, would JQuery need to be involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you won't be able to do that.

What you can do is that use an input type="file", make the transparency as 100% put an anchor behind that.

You can see a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xUfMP/1/).

Comment: Okay but I don't understand what you mean by putting an anchor tag behind a transparent input.

Comment: The question was `is it possible to call up the system's file upload window with an anchor tag`. Thats why I suggested to put an anchor tag which will be visible to the user.

Comment: Yes but how does the anchor tag control the input?

Comment: <span id="add_files"><a href="#">Add more files</a></span>
<input type="file"/> So how do I position the elements?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Jquery plugin. http://valums.com/ajax-upload/
The solution is make the input type="file" transparent and put your custom button upon it.
The input type="file" can't be triggered programmatically, but just with a real interaction by the user (in this case a mouse click)

Comment: Thanks Stefano. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Possible if you trick it a little bit.

HTML:

```
<a href='#' id='#upfile1'>Upload File</a>
<input type="file" id="file1"  name="file1" style="display:none" />
```

JQuery:

```
$("#upfile1").click(function () {
    $("#file1").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The input tag should be hidden. Change the CSS according to your wish.

HTML:

```
<input id="upload" type="file"/>
<a href="" id="upload_link">Upload your file</a>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $("#upload_link").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#upload:hidden").trigger('click');
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#upload_link{text-decoration:none;}
#upload{display:none}
```